# Mysql return only items that have n number of property matches

Tags: php, mysql, select, grouping

I have a database of items and each item has various number of properties. Is it possible for MySql only to return items that have a certain number of matches (not properties) when a search is run?

Example: I am searching for any item with a wheel that is red and has a tire. 
This would return all items with these three matches even if they have more properties and would automatically exclude anything that has less than 3 matches.

I have tried playing with the COUNT + GROUP BY + HAVING but I was unable to put together a meaningful working code. Before I spend more time on this I would like to know if it is possible at all.

TABLE DESIGN

```
ID ITEM PROPERTY
1  1    red
2  1    wheel
3  1    tire
4  2    red
5  2    wheel
6  2    tire
7  2    lamp
8  3    red
9  3    wheel
10 4    red
```

I would like it to return ITEM 1 and 2

Comment: I cannot think of an easy way to do this for a large n, but how about something like `select * from table where ((wheels > 0) + (color = "red") + (tires > 0)) >= 3` ... does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this with a `group by` and `having`.  You really provide no information about your data structure, but the basic idea is:

```
select ip.item
from design ip
where ip.property in ('wheel', 'red', 'tire')
group by ip.item
having count(distinct ip.property) = 3;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I added the basic table design and a sample data set. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind adjusting your code with the sample data set above. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What does the "ip" stand for and why is it needed? As you can see my MySql knowledge is not the greatest.

Comment: It is a table alias.  It is not needed in this case, but it is a good idea.  It tells you which table each column is coming from.